# iOS Localizations changing, native region

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I developed an app, that contains a few input plist files, with input data for this app.
This input data now is in russian language.

During developing process I intended to distribute this app only at Russian AppStore for russian speaking customers. Now my app is in AppStore. But now I also want to distribute my app for english speaking customers.
I know that I have to prepare translated input plists with input data in english language.

My question concerns more localizations in the app..

During development I changed info.plist file, I set "Localization native development region" to "ru".

What is the most correct way to solve my case?
Should I leave "Localization native development region" set to "ru" and add English localization?
Or should I set "Localization native development region" back to "en" and add Russian localization?
Or maybe I should add two localizations - english and russian? In this case, what option should I set to "Localization native development region"?

And by the way, how can I choose programmatically which one input data plist file read depending of current localization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should change the Localization native development region to en region, from the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-130430):

> CFBundleDevelopmentRegion (String - iOS, OS X) specifies the default
>   language and region for the bundle, as a language ID. For example,
>   English for the United Kingdom has the language ID en-UK. The system
>   uses this value if it cannot locate a resource for the user’s
>   preferred language

Count of English speakers more on the world then count of Russian speakers. If the location system can't finds needed localizations it will use your native language file. 
But if you use a [method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/URLForResource:withExtension:subdirectory:localization:) of NSBundle to load native resources (for example a plist):

```
- (NSURL *)URLForResource:(NSString *)name
            withExtension:(NSString *)extension
             subdirectory:(NSString *)subpath
             localization:(NSString *)localizationName
//The file URL for the resource file or nil if the file could not be located.
```

You should add non a localized plist file, to avoid returning nil URL from this method for unsupported localization (a file with same name but not in a lang directory).

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AccessingaBundlesContents/AccessingaBundlesContents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH104-SW7) you can read how NSBundle finds resources if you request those.

Comment: Tjhank you! And for localizationName - how to correct call english or russian localization?

Comment: Details about my initial question:
I use this one:
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:pathName ofType:@"plist"];

to  get path for input plist file. Then I parse contents of file to nsdictionary and to some object..
So I want to get path for english version of this file if there's English localization chosen by user, and russian version if Russian localization choosen. How can I do this?

Comment: Do have setting of the location in your application, or you use default implementation of localization sytem. If use use the default implementation, you should only  add en and ru languages directories, and change native language to en and all should work from the box. If you want use inner language subsystem (change language in the application), you should load the plist  using localized method (i've showed it  before) and add non localized plist file.